# ActiveReport Truncate A Text

Tags: vb6, activereports

I make a Report in ActiveReport3.0 which has a Subreport. In my subreport, in the Detail part actually, I have a textbox , that I bind my value to the textbox.datafield. my value is a text in persian and it is also long(about 8000 words).( I read the Value from Sql).I set the
alignment of the textbox to "rtl" because my text is in persian.
 then when I run my app, the activereport truncate my text in persian (truncate it from left and right of the textbox not at the bottom).what is the problem?

Comment: `CanGrow = True`? `MultiLine = True`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue mentioned by you was not replicable. You may refer to the [rpx file](http://speedy.sh/4TMtf/Report.rpx) wherein persian text is assigned to Textbox and no clipping is observed.

The attached report was created with latest build of [AR3](http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/72/ShowForum.aspx) (5.3.1436.2). You may try using this build and should not face any issues thereafter.

Regards,
Mohita